# Inserting a row in pandas by searching and using an order priority

Tags: python, pandas

Hi i have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
#Create DF
d = { 
     'EventNo-Name': ['2021-Normal-1-Joe','2021-Normal-2-Jack','2021-Normal-3-John','2021-Normal-4-James','2021-Normal-5-Jim'],
    'Priority':[18,17,16,15,14],
    }
           
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

[image]

*EDIT*
Rows are added at different times and not together.

Day 1:
I would like to insert a row  `['2021-Priority-1-Josh', 20]` above the row that contains `2021-Normal-1` within the `EventNo` row so that my result equals:

[image]

Day 2:
The next day i have second priority row `['2021-Priority-1-Jimmy', 21]` which i would like to insert that also above the row that contains `2021-Normal-1` within the `EventNo` but also above the `2021-Priority-1-Josh` row because the priority number is larger. My desired result is:

[image]

This one is a bit above my python levels but ideally if there is one function to cover both quesitons then that would be great! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It will have been more helpful if you told us how the new lists occur. Anyway, I assume you get a list at a time. If thats the case, combine the lists into one.

Once you have combined, bring the corresponfind elements into a new list. Map each list in the new list of lists onto existing columns. Generate a new dataframe. Append this dataframe to the existing. Sort the resulting by Priority. Code below

```
l1=['2021-Priority-1-Josh', 20]
l2=['2021-Priority-1-Jimmy', 21]

lis=[l1,l2]

df.append(pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(df.columns,[list(x) for x in zip(*lis)])))).sort_values(by='Priority', ascending=False)
```

Outcome

```
     EventNo-Name      Priority
1  2021-Priority-1-Jimmy        21
0   2021-Priority-1-Josh        20
0      2021-Normal-1-Joe        18
1     2021-Normal-2-Jack        17
2     2021-Normal-3-John        16
3    2021-Normal-4-James        15
4      2021-Normal-5-Jim        14
```

How it works

```
# Combine like elements in the two lists

l1=[list(x) for x in zip(*lis)]

#Generate a dataframe constructor

d1 =dict(zip(df.columns,l1)) #

#Generate a dataframe 

df1 =pd.DataFrame(d1)

#append to old Dataframe

df.append(df1).sort_values(by='Priority', ascending=False)
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This is helpful. Sorry i should have mentioned that they come in as input statements so not always at the same time. Which is a problem Im trying to get around. but potentialy i could use your solution as above and then do a sort values like this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523262/how-to-sort-subset-of-rows-in-pandas-data-frame

Comment: Edit your question and tell us what you really need. We shouldn't be modelling our answers on a different question. What do you need done? Or what's does this solution fail to do?